# Why does my background-image move on hover? :(

Tags: css, hover, padding

[My problem is here](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-n1DI0_YZE4I/VOyJrho_S3I/AAAAAAAABEk/IJhUuxs4zd8/s1600/Bez%2Bn%C3%A1zvu.png)

Hi, can somebody tells me, where is the problem? 
My background-image just moving after hover the li with class .cerny
Here is my code.

```
 aside nav ul {
           list-style-type:none;
           margin:0;
           padding:0;
           margin-top:25px;
        }


    li.cerny {
        height:50px;
        background: url("images/cerny.png") no-repeat top left;
        margin-left:-24.2px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
                }
        .cerny:hover {
        color:black;
        background: url("images/menu_hover.png") no-repeat top left;
        }

   .cerny a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:wheat;
        display:block;
        padding-top:18px;
        padding-left:40px;
        font-size:15px;
 <aside>
     <nav>
          <ul>
  <li class="cerny"><a href="#"  style="margin-top:20px;">Můj statek</a></li>  
  <li class="cerny"><a href="#">Tržiště</a></li> 
  <li class="cerny"><a href="#">Město</a></li> 
  <li class="cerny"><a href="#">Soutěžní centrum</a></li>  
  <li class="cerny"><a href="#">Okolí</a></li>  
          </ul>
    </nav>
 </aside>
```

Comment: Are images `cerny.png` and `menu_hover.png` the same size? In dimension.

Comment: It depends on your background images. Can you provide your `cerny.png` and `menu_hover.png` files so that I can check if that's the case?

Comment: Most likely you're images are not aligned properly in respect to each other  to begin with. i.e. an image with a red box and 10px of padding (in the image) all around for default state and then a blue box for hover state. Yet the blue box has 10px (top), 5px (right), 10px (bottom) and 15px (left) padding. If something like this is going on in your images then you would see a shift as the left padding/spacing is different in each image.

Comment: Omg my mistake -_- damn photoshop.. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your images (`cerny.png` and `menu_hover.png`) size are not same. check that in Photoshop.